# Conexión para consultar a otro servidor PosgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell

Quisiera saber ¿cómo puedo consulto a otro servidor postgresql sin que me pida nuevamente el **password**? ya que lo ejecutaré mediante un *shell*.

le muestro el mensaje que aparece:

> postgres@edward:/home/administrador/scripts$ psql -U postgres -W PASSWORD -h aaaa.yyy.zzz.xxx -d outi -c 'select * from alert.backups;' -t

psql: warning: extra command-line argument "eimeXeithohc1eiy" ignored
Password for user postgres:

como pueden observar me  pide nuevamente el **password** agradeceré su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimados encontre la solucion la cual es bien sensilla y es la siguiente:

Editar el archivo pg_hba.conf que se encuentra dentro del main de la ruta de POSTGRES con lo siguiente.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host     BD              usuario           IPORIGEN/32        trust
```

La IPORIGEN es el sevidor desde donde realizaras la consulta.

La BD es la base de datos a la cual realizara las consultas o cambios
TRUST es para indicarle que es confiable.

Comment: Si se solucionó tu pregunta con la respuesta de Anthony marcala como correcta, si en cambio no te funcionó, pero si se soluciono con tu investigación. Marca tu respuesta como correcta.

Comment: tener cuidado con el trust en el pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el archivo .pgpass para eso de no tener que colocar password

Las entradas de ese archivo suelen ser algo como esto

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

Si tienes alguna duda consulta la documentación de ese archivo

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

Saludos

Comment: Buen Día Anthony.
Disculpa pero no encuentro el archivo que mencionas mi S.O es ubuntu.Haber si me das una mano

Comment: Es  un archivo oculto que debe estar en el home del usuario que está ejecutando el comando psql, si no existe créalo con el formato de entrada ese que te comenté en la respuesta y dale permisos 600